# RegExp must return hashtags with special conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not strong in regular expressions, so I need regExp for validating a hashtags.
All hashtags should be marked according to the rules:

- always use the # before your chosen keywords.
- do not use punctuation or spaces in hashtags.
- never put characters immediately before the #.
- use letters and numbers, never numbers alone.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  str: string =
    "#des.ign #living?room #how? #”your”dream #des’ign #new,story ##des-ign #des—ign #new! #des:ign #des;ign #(des#) #[de#s] #new... #des4u/. #12345.";
  text: string = "";
  replaceAll: any;
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.showText(this.str);
  }
  showText = (str) => {
    const regex = /#\^[A-Za-z0-9]/g;
    this.text = str.replace(regex, (value) => `<p>${value}</p>`);
    return this.text;
  };
}
```

Comment: What is the output do you want to achieve?

Comment: #design #livingroom #how #yourdream #design #newstory #design #design #new #design #design #des #des #new #des #des4u #12345.

Comment: Why have you edited the input `str`? Is that your expected output? So what is the input now?

Comment: Sorry, I wrongly edited little bit input string, look now.

Comment: Гриша, why do you expect `#12349108` to become `#12345`? You say this kind of hashtags should be ignored.

Comment: My fault! "#12345." must be "#12345." ---> numbers with dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract all these hashtags first with a pattern like `((?:^|\s)#)#*([^#\s]\S*)` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tA3VA8/3/)) and then post-process matches by removing unexpected chars from Group 1 value, that will be your result.

Note it is not possible to achieve what you need with a single regex matching or replacing operation, so you can use

```js
var string = "#des.ign #living?room #how? #”your”dream #des’ign #new,story ##des-ign #des—ign #new! #des:ign #des;ign #(des#) #[de#s] #new... #des4u/. #12349108.";
var rx = /((?:^|\s)#)#*([^#\s]\S*)/g;
var rx_special = /[^A-Za-z\d]/g;
console.log(
  string.replace(rx, (m, first, second) => first + second.replace(rx_special, ''))
);
```

Output:

```js
#design #livingroom #how #yourdream #design #newstory #design #design #new #design #design #des #des #new #des4u #12349108
```

*Regex details*

- `((?:^|\s)#)` - Group 1: start of string or whitespace and then a `#`
- `#*` - zero or more `#` chars
- `([^#\s]\S*)` - Group 2: any char other than `#` and whitespace and then any zero or more non-whitespace chars.
- `[^A-Za-z\d]` - matches any char other than ASCII letter or digit.

Comment: Thank U for right answer man! 
One more detail, "#12345." must be "#12345." ---> numbers with dot.

Comment: @ГригорийСидорин Then you need to remove the last requirement in your question, namely *"use letters and numbers, never numbers alone."* Then, you can simply remove `var rx_digit = /^\d+$/;` and the `rx_digit.test(...)`. I modified the answer.

Comment: Doesn't work correctly. "#12345." must be "#12345." ---> numbers with dot. Return "#12345"

Comment: @ГригорийСидорин This requires a bit more clarification: do you mean `#12345.` should not be even matched, or if `#1$23%45%#%.` should be converted to `#12345.`?

Comment: I mean if we hawe string like "#12345." (hashteg + numbers+ dot) we need to get in output the same result "#12345.", if we get string "#12345" (hashteg + numbers) it mustn't much as a hashtag.

Comment: @ГригорийСидорин Try the updated solution.

Comment: Yes you are right, if we have "#12345" (hashteg + numbers) or "#12345." (hashteg + numbers+ dot) it it mustn't much as a hashtag. Can I ask you to revert the solution as it was in first variant?

Comment: @ГригорийСидорин OK, rolled back to Rev2.